# How to know if the deployment on Netlify is done via API?

Tags: api, deployment, netlify

I successfully deployed a site from my web app using Netlify API, but I don’t know how to get the info that if the deployment is done or not.

I thought the response from [get-deploy](https://docs.netlify.com/api/get-started/#get-deploy) can be the answer, especially the `summary.status` of that response.

I tried to keep calling the `/api/v1/sites/:site_id/deploys/:deploy_id` endpoint every 5 sec and watching `summary.status`, however, the value of `summary.status` has never changed from `building` even after the deployment has been done.

[image: API response]

How can I get this kind of data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the `/api/v1/sites/:site_id/deploys/:deploy_id` endpoint is the right way to do it, [they say](https://community.netlify.com/t/how-to-know-if-the-deployment-on-netlify-is-done-via-api/23870).

Comment: @double-beep Thanks!